# Message selector options JMSCorrelationID or simple string as a JMS property

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Which message selector option is good ? JMSCorrelationID or simple string as a JMS property to selectively fetch messages from queue ? I believe, in term of performance they are same.

```
Producer side using string property:
message = session.CreateTextMessage(msg);
message.setString("myfilter", "abc");
producer.sent(message);

Producer side using JMSCorrelation ID : 
message = session.CreateTextMessage(msg);
message.setJMSCorrelationID("abc")
producer.sent(message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what property(or properties) ActiveMQ indexes messages. I would expect messages to be indexed on message identifier and correlation identifier because these are the two properties on which messages are searched frequently.  Indexing messages on application specific properties is highly unlikely.  So JMSCorrelationID would be your best choice.

Comment: I'm not sure, if this is correct and also one more point of difference. if we use correlation id, client get all messages and does filtering using correlation id. if we use message specific property broker does filtering for client.